# Laravel Error on error page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have installed the latest version of the Laravel 5.4 (before I worked with 4.2). Everything works perfect, but when I make a mistake in my application (eg. I use a class from another namespace without "use" at the beginning of the document), Laravel displays following error:

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException | The "" directory does not exist.

[image: Red error page]

instead of the correct error. 
I think the correct error page doesn't display correctly and here is why this happens.

I tried to run:

```
$ composer install
$ composer composer dump-autoload
```

But the error still appears.

Comment: Did you install composer without any errors?

Comment: First check storage/logs/laravel.log for errors. If it is empty check \var\log\apache2\error.log

Comment: @Sunny: Yes, without errors.

Comment: @Troyer laravel.log shows correct error (eg. Cannot use Illuminate\Http\Request as Request because the name is already in use), but on Laravel error page is still a message: "InvalidArgumentException
The "" directory does not exist."

Comment: @ZaquPL Can you please show your controller?